# : mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,

Tags: php, mysqli

in my previous problem i already solved it, i just put this inside the mysqli_error() `$this->connection

i tried to re-program these section but still cant fix it. 
error message.
: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,

```
public function mysql_prep( $value ) {
    $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
    $new_enough_php = function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" ); // i.e. PHP >= v4.3.0
    if( $new_enough_php ) { // PHP v4.3.0 or higher
        // undo any magic quote effects so mysql_real_escape_string can do the work
        if( $magic_quotes_active ) { $value = stripslashes($value); }
        $value = mysqli_real_escape_string( $value);
    } else { // before PHP v4.3.0
        // if magic quotes aren't already on then add slashes manually
        if( !$magic_quotes_active ) { $value = addslashes( $value ); }
        // if magic quotes are active, then the slashes already exist
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Use `mysqli_connect_error()` to determine the error from the last connection, not `mysqli_error()`. For future reference, `mysqli_error()` requires a parameter (the connection) like `$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM tbl') or die (mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: I suspect you don't have display_errors turned on, since you would be seeing PHP errors related to a the missing parameter to `mysqli_query()`.. Always do this when developing code:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I see now that the error you're seeing is on `database selection failed`.  There, you need the parameter to `mysqli_error($this->connection)`, as you still have a call to `mysql_error()`.  The two API's are _not_ compatible and you cannot mix functions between them.

Comment: And you have a misspelling: `$this->conenction`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you do error detection and reporting properly, you should have more info on the cause for the failure.

Here's an example function that should be more successful at displaying the errors:

```
public function open_connection() {
    // CREATE DATABASE CONNECTION 
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) { 
        die("Database Connection Failed:".mysqli_connect_error()); 
    }
    // SELECT A DATABASE TO USE.
    if (!mysqli_select_db($this->connection, DB_NAME)) {
        die("Database selection failed: ".mysqli_error($this->connection));
    }
}
```

Also note that you can mysqli_connect() and select the database in one step, which is something the deprecated mysql_connect() could not do.

```
public function open_connection() {
    // CREATE DATABASE CONNECTION AND SELECT A DATABASE
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) { 
        die("Database Connection Failed:".mysqli_connect_error()); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lets go step by step :)

1. `$this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);` instead can u write directly using the values instead of defined one ? something like this `$this->connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123456");`
2. just below that run a query instead to confirm if the connection is open suppose you have table name "user" then write a simple select query  `$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user",$this->connection) or die(mysql_error());`

Hope got what i tried to convey... and hope it helps

thx